# Booting laptop automatically

Tags: laptop, boot, bios, automation, timer

How can I have a laptop with Phoenix BIOS and an Intel 2010 processor automatically boot at a given time?

Comment: Maybe. Have you looked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows and your laptop supports it, you can create a scheduled task and check the box "Wake the computer to run this task" under the Settings tab.

Comment: That will only wake it from sleep levels. It won't work if the computer is entirely powered off, i.e. turned off or in hibernate.

Comment: @nhinkle: actually most systems support waking from S4 (hibernate), and some from S5 (soft-off). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface and http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup

Answer (score 0):

You could have another computer wake it via the "wake on LAN" feature in the BIOS. Is this an option?

Comment: +1 for WOL and another PC in the same network with a scheduled task to wake the first PC up.